# wordpress page link to the post

Tags: wordpress, url, post, hyperlink

I need to set up on a wordpress blog so that the user can insert a link to another page in a new post.
I need to automate the creation of a link to another page so that after inserting a new post that will contain http, this post will automatically appear as a link and not as plain text.
I tried plugins Frontend Post Submission Manager Lite , User Submitted Posts but I didn't succeed with theme.
can you please advise me how to do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: for example, after inserting this text, it will automatically be created as a link to the given page: https://www.dailyautomation.sk/